# Retrieve ComboBox items from DataGridView vb. Net

Tags: vb.net

I have searched in various sources, friends, google and others, but I did not find an answer to my problem above, I am very grateful if anyone is willing to help me

Comment: Please read [ask] and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please really consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, as Nico already mentioned. It is considered most helpful to describe your exact problem, maybe a description of what _exactly_ you already tried and a helpful [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The better your question (quality, not quantity), the better and quicker the answers!